# Android ListView single click context menu

Tags: android, listview

I have a list of items that for each short click I want to display a custom context menu.  I have looked all over for an example and tried a lot of things but the closest I can come is to have the menu showup on a long-click (and the menu was not distinct per item).  Here is the code, any assistance would be great.  Notice that after reading a bunch of tutorials I have subclassed from Activity.

```
public class EventListActivity extends Activity {

      @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              Log.i("ME", "Event List Activity Into On Create ");
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.event_list);
            Log.i("ME", "Event List Activity Into On Create 1 ");
            String[] values = new String[] {"Emerald Greens","Dahlgtreen","Edinborough","Pebble Creek","Gross"};
            Log.i("ME", "Event List Activity Into On Create 2");

            ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

            Log.i("ME", "Event List Activity Into On Create 2a");


            //ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.event_list,R.id.label,values);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.event_list_item,values);

            Log.i("ME", "Event List Activity Into On Create 3");
            //setListAdapter(adapter);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            Log.i("ME", "Event List Activity Into On Create 4");

            registerForContextMenu(listView);
            Log.i("ME", "Event List Activity Into On Create 6");

      }




    protected void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View v, int pos, long id) {
        String item = (String)listView.getAdapter().getItem(pos);
        Toast.makeText(this, item+" Selected pos:"+pos+":   id:"+id+":", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }   


    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        Log.i("ME", "OnCreateContextMenu ");
      if (v.getId()==R.id.list) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;
        //menu.setHeaderTitle(Countries[info.position]);
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Blippo");
        //String[] menuItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu);
        String[] menuItems = new String[] {"Menu a","Menub"};
        for (int i = 0; i<menuItems.length; i++) {
          menu.add(Menu.NONE, i, i, menuItems[i]);
        }
      }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
      int menuItemIndex = item.getItemId();
      //String[] menuItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu);
      String[] menuItems = new String[] {"Menu a","Menub"};
      String menuItemName = menuItems[menuItemIndex];

      //String listItemName = Countries[info.position];
      String listItemName = "hardcoded";

      Toast.makeText(this, item+" Selected Submenu", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

      return true;
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use sliding drawer for this on click of every item you can open your sliding drawer and display your items

Answer (score 0):

Its android rule that contextMenu can be pop up only when you perform long click on view that has associated contextMenu with it.So i want to make clear that it not possible on any other event.

```
Second Problem--> menu was not distinct per item
```

You are registering menu to ListView so how can it detect the item.When you long click same contextMenu will open.When you click any row that row is listView so it will open same menu.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do it on single click, why don't you try to open custom dialog, with list of action(option) , open this dialog on list item click, and close it when you choose one action.

Comment: Do you have some samples of how to do this or a website I can check out?

Comment: let me suggest one thing, I hope you know how to show a listview with many rows,
1) create an activity, in this activity show a list of action, 
2) when you want to show context menu on item click. open this activity.
3) add theme:dialog in your activity declaration in manifest file, so new activity will look like a popup dialog. and take an action and finish this activity..

Answer (score 0):

Context menu will work only on Long click. If you want me to provide you the code to perform some action on list item onclick() and open a context menu on list item long click,please let me know.